# Migrate SQL Server database with 100 million rows and 40g size to mongodb

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, migrate, database

We have a SQL Server database with 100 million rows and 40g size. Our server has 24 cpu and 150g ram. SQL Server uses 100% of cpu. The server is in critical situation.

What is the best solution for migrating to mongodb?

Are there any tools for doing this work?

Comment: What makes you think just migration to MongoDB will solve any of your "problems"? (if you even have any...)

Comment: @marc_s I think mongodb is faster and has better performance

Comment: Based on what **facts** ??? SQL Server can be very very fast - if the database design is solid and the T-SQL programming is done really well ..... and again - just by switching to MongoDB, I don't see how your system would suddenly run faster...... but try - and if it is - great for you!

Answer (score 4):

*Note:* This is more an extended comment than an answer.

[ 1 ] 40 GB database isn't a big / huge database. It's more a medium size database (or small to medium database).

[ 2 ] At first sight I see no reason why I would migrate to mongodb a such DB with such hardware (24 *core* ?! CPU, 150 GB RAM).

[ 3 ] From my point of view, the most likely causes of low / slow performance of db server could be:

- SQL Server missconfiguration (for example: see max memory) and or Win Server configuration,
- cpu and/or memory pressure generated by external processes (for example: are you running IIS web server on the same machine),
- Missing indexes ?
- Poor programming T-SQL skills (for example: cursors).

[ 4 ] I would hire a consulting company to analyze this this SQL instance.
See:

Brent Ozar Limited https://www.brentozar.com/sql-critical-care/
and/or

SQLSkills https://www.sqlskills.com/services/
and/or

Steve Stedman http://stevestedman.com/consulting/ and/or

google for "sql server consulting"

@ontopic:

Source: http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2014/06/03/the-problem-is-not-the-tool-itself/[image]